# Updating SVN local changes is not finished in Intellij IDEA 15.0.6

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I am new to Intellij IDEA, I am using IDEA version 15.0.6.
I modified some files in my project, now I want to see the list of changed files, so that I can commit those files into SVN.

But, Intellij is not displaying the list of changed files.
 - I clicked "refresh" icon under Version Control -> Local Changes, Intellij says **"updating" for hours and hours**, but there is no list yet.

[image]

- After I did, Right click on file -> Subversion -> Commit File...

VCS (Subversion) refresh is in progress, This refresh is in progress for more than 1 hour, but I am not getting "commit" window even after waiting for 1 hour.

[image]

- There is a background task (**looking for .... working copy root**),which is running all the time , there is no "close" button to stop this background task.

[image]

Please refer these screenshots and suggest me to solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like a bug in IntelliJ IDEA that results in problems with locating the working copy's root. You'd better contact their support for assistance. Or check whether this reproduces with a clean versioned project.

Comment: @bahrep, Thanks, I even tried by uninstall & installed IDEA, still same issue occurs in the newly imported project

Comment: I reported this issue to Intellij and waiting for reply now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by the **official support team**, I configured **commandline client** (**TortoiseSVN**) as shown in this screenshot.

Now, SVN issues are **solved**.

File ->Settings ->Version Control -> Subversion -> Use commandline client

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Was looking for this. Although I have to **Restart Android Studio** after making changes to take effect.